# Only static member in initializer

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to do some tutorial and encountered some problem when passing a class object to my widget and I am completely lost with this...

```
class Planet {
  String id;
  String name;
  String location;
  String distance;
  String gravity;
  String description;
  String image;
  String picture;

  Planet({this.id, this.name, this.location, this.distance, this.gravity, this.description, this.image, this.picture});
}

List<Planet> planets = <Planet>[
  Planet(
      id: "1",
      name: "Mars",
      location: "Milkyway Galaxy",
      distance: "54.6m Km",
      gravity: "3.711 m/s ",
      description:
          "Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and the second-smallest planet in the Solar System after Mercury. In English, Mars carries a name of the Roman god of war, and is often referred to as the 'Red Planet' because the reddish iron oxide prevalent on its surface gives it a reddish appearance that is distinctive among the astronomical bodies visible to the naked eye. Mars is a terrestrial planet with a thin atmosphere, having surface features reminiscent both of the impact craters of the Moon and the valleys, deserts, and polar ice caps of Earth.",
      image: "assets/images/mars.png",
      picture: "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia21723-16.jpg"),
];
```

and in my widget I have:

```
class PlanetSummary extends StatelessWidget {
 final Planet planet;

 PlanetSummary(this.planet);

final Widget _planetThumbnail = new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
    alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
    child: new Image(
      image: new AssetImage(planet.image),  // <---- ERROR (planet.name) only static member can be accessed in initializers 
      height: 92.0,
      width: 92.0,
    ),
  );
```

I completely don't understand this error can someone help ?

Comment: @RaoufRahiche even tho that issue don't give me any clue at all how could I resolve my problem, unfortunately.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class member variable planet, (because its not static variable) will get its value in constructor, so we can not use one non static class member variable to assign value to another non static class member. If you wan't to use planet to assign value to your widget, change your class to StatefulWidget and you may try to just declare non final variable _planetThumbnail and assign its value in iniState method of class

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _planetThumbnail = <your widget initialization code>
}
```

of if you want to use StatelessWidget class only, then just create _planetThumbnil widget in build method only and use it.

Comment: ohhhh god... Okay Now I get it !!!! lel Thank You ! :)